# Getting http response code from javascript function

Tags: javascript

Hello i’m new to this community and to javascript too.

I want to create a function  that will take a url as argument and return the htpp status code of that website. (404, 200, 403 etc).

```js
function getStatus(url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD',url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status;
}
```

I tried this but isn’t working.
Is there something else better than this that i can do i vanilla javascript.

Ps. The link that it says this question is already asked is not waht i wanted

Comment: You will only get that status *later* when the request has resolved, for which you need `onreadystatechange`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: You *will* need that duplicate link once you follow my above advice about `onreadystatechange`…!

Comment: Okay thanks I’ll try